# __init__() takes exactly 3 arguments (1 given)?

Tags: python, arguments, init

It is asking for 3 arguments and i have given it one. How do i give it 2 more and could you explain how to do that as well? Thanks

```
import pygame, random, collisionObjects
pygame.init()

screen = pygame.display.set_mode((640,480))

class Pirate(pygame.sprite.Sprite):

    EAST = 0

    def __init__(self, screen, dx):
        self.screen = screen
        pygame.sprite.Sprite.__init__(self)
        self.image = pygame.image.load("king_pirate/running e0000.bmp")
        self.image = self.image.convert()
        tranColor = self.image.get_at((1, 1))
        self.image.set_colorkey(tranColor)
        self.rect = self.image.get_rect()
        self.rect.inflate_ip(-50, -30)
        self.rect.center = (0, random.randrange(30,450))
        self.img = []

        self.loadPics()
        self.frame = 0
        self.delay = 4
        self.pause = self.delay
        self.dx = dx


    def update(self):
        #set delay
        self.pause -= 1
        if self.pause <= 0:
            self.pause = self.delay

            self.frame += 1
            if self.frame > 7:
                self.frame = 0

            self.image = self.img[self.frame]

            self.rect.centerx += self.dx
            if self.rect.centerx > self.screen.get_width():
                self.rect.centerx = 0
                self.rect.centery = random.randrange(30,450)

    #load pictures
    def loadPics(self):
        for i in range(8):
            imgName = "king_pirate/running e000%d.bmp" % i
            tmpImg = pygame.image.load(imgName)
            tmpImg.convert()
            tranColor = tmpImg.get_at((0, 0))
            tmpImg.set_colorkey(tranColor)
            self.img.append(tmpImg)

class Pirate2(pygame.sprite.Sprite):

    WEST = 0

    def __init__(self, screen, dx):
        self.screen = screen
        pygame.sprite.Sprite.__init__(self)
        self.image = pygame.image.load("pirate/running w0000.bmp")
        self.image = self.image.convert()
        tranColor = self.image.get_at((1, 1))
        self.image.set_colorkey(tranColor)
        self.rect = self.image.get_rect()
        self.rect.inflate_ip(-50, -30)
        self.rect.center = (640, random.randrange(20,460))
        self.img = []

        self.loadPics()
        self.frame = 0
        self.delay = 4
        self.pause = self.delay
        self.dx = dx       


    def update(self):
        #set delay
        self.pause -= 1
        if self.pause <= 0:
            self.pause = self.delay

            self.frame += 1
            if self.frame > 7:
                self.frame = 0

            self.image = self.img[self.frame]

            self.rect.centerx -= self.dx
            if self.rect.centerx < 0:
                self.rect.centerx = self.screen.get_width()
                self.rect.centery = random.randrange(20,460)

    #load pictures
    def loadPics(self):
        for i in range(8):
            imgName = "pirate/running w000%d.bmp" % i
            tmpImg = pygame.image.load(imgName)
            tmpImg.convert()
            tranColor = tmpImg.get_at((0, 0))
            tmpImg.set_colorkey(tranColor)
            self.img.append(tmpImg)

#set up class for gold object,
class Gold(pygame.sprite.Sprite):          
    def __init__(self, screen, imageFile):
        pygame.sprite.Sprite.__init__(self)
        self.image = pygame.image.load(imageFile)
        self.image = self.image.convert()
        self.rect = self.image.get_rect()
        self.rect.centerx = random.randrange(0, screen.get_width())
        self.rect.centery = random.randrange(0, screen.get_height())

#main character class
class Thief(pygame.sprite.Sprite):
    def __init__(self):
        pygame.sprite.Sprite.__init__(self)
        self.image = pygame.image.load("thief2.gif")
        self.image = self.image.convert()
        tranColor = self.image.get_at((1, 1))
        self.image.set_colorkey(tranColor)
        self.rect = self.image.get_rect()
        self.rect.inflate_ip(-15, -10)
        self.rect.center = (30, (screen.get_height()-40))
        self.dx = 30
        self.dy = 30

        if not pygame.mixer:
            print("problem with sound")
        else:
            pygame.mixer.init()
            self.collectcoin = pygame.mixer.Sound("collectcoin.wav")
            self.hit = pygame.mixer.Sound("hit.ogg")


    def update(self):
        if self.rect.bottom > screen.get_height():
            self.rect.centery = (screen.get_height()-40)         
        elif self.rect.top < 0:
            self.rect.centery = 40
        elif self.rect.right > screen.get_width():
            self.rect.centerx = (screen.get_width()-30)         
        elif self.rect.left < 0:
            self.rect.centerx = 30

    #define movements
    def moveUp(self):
        self.rect.centery -= self.dy

    def moveDown(self):
        self.rect.centery += self.dy

    def moveLeft(self):
        self.rect.centerx -= self.dx

    def moveRight(self):
        self.rect.centerx += self.dx

    def reset(self):
        self.rect.center = (30, (screen.get_height()-40))

#set up a scoreboard        
class Scoreboard(pygame.sprite.Sprite):
    def __init__(self):
        pygame.sprite.Sprite.__init__(self)
        self.lives = 0
        self.score = 0
        self.font = pygame.font.SysFont("None", 40)
        self.number = 0

    #with a self updating label
    def update(self):
        self.text = "Damage: %d %%  Gold Taken: %d" % (self.lives, self.score)
        self.image = self.font.render(self.text, 1, (199,237,241))
        self.rect = self.image.get_rect()

#define the game function
def game():
    #set up background
    background = pygame.Surface(screen.get_size())
    background = pygame.image.load("sand.jpg")
    background = pygame.transform.scale(background, screen.get_size())
    screen.blit(background, (0, 0))

    #initialize pirates & scoreboard sprites
    pirate = Pirate()
    scoreboard = Scoreboard()

    #create two arrays for multiple gold object occurances
    #two arrays are used for better distribution on screen
    gold1 = []
    numberofGold = 16
    for i in range(numberofgolds):
        oneGold = golds(screen,"gold1.png")
        golds1.append(onegold)
    for gold in golds1:
        gold.rect.centerx = random.randrange(20,620)
        gold.rect.centery = random.randrange(20,240)
        gold.rect.inflate_ip(-5, -5)
    gold2 = []
    for i in range(numberofgolds):
        onegold = golds(screen,"gold1.png")
        golds2.append(onegold)
    for gold in golds2:
        gold.rect.centerx = random.randrange(20,620)
        gold.rect.centery = random.randrange(250,460)
        gold.rect.inflate_ip(-5, -5)
    totalgolds = ((len(golds1)-1)+(len(golds2)-1))
    #initialize gold sprites
    goldSprites = pygame.sprite.Group(golds1, 
    #initialize pirate sprites & instances
    pirate1 = pirate1(screen,13)
    pirate2 = pirate2(screen,13)
    pirate3 = pirate1(screen,11)
    pirate4 = pirate2(screen,11)
    pirate5 = pirate1(screen,13)
    pirateSprites = pygame.sprite.Group(pirate1, pirate2, pirate3, pirate4, pirate5)

    #use ordered updates to keep clean appearance
    allSprites =  pygame.sprite.OrderedUpdates(goldSprites, thief, pirateSprites, scoreboard)

    #set up clock & loop
    clock = pygame.time.Clock()
    keepGoing = True
    while keepGoing:
        clock.tick(30)
        for event in pygame.event.get():
            if event.type == pygame.QUIT:
                keepGoing = False
            elif event.type == pygame.KEYDOWN:
                if event.key == pygame.K_UP:
                    thief.moveUp()
                elif event.key == pygame.K_DOWN:
                    thief.moveDown()
                elif event.key == pygame.K_LEFT:
                    thief.moveLeft()
                elif event.key == pygame.K_RIGHT:
                    thief.moveRight()
                elif event.key == pygame.K_ESCAPE:
                    keepGoing = False

        #check collisions here
        hitpirates = pygame.sprite.spritecollide(thief, pirateSprites, False)
        hitgold = pygame.sprite.spritecollide(thief, goldSprites, True)

        if hitpirates:
            thief.hit.play()
            scoreboard.lives += 1
            if scoreboard.lives >= 100:
                keepGoing = False
                number = 0


        if hitgolds:
            thief.collectcoin.play()
            scoreboard.score += 1
            totalgolds -= 1
            if totalgolds <= 0:
                keepGoing = False
                number = 1


        #draw sprites
        allSprites.clear(screen, background)
        allSprites.update()
        allSprites.draw(screen)

        pygame.display.flip()

    return scoreboard.score
    return scoreboard.number

def instructions(score, number):
    pygame.display.set_caption("Hunt for Gold!")

    background = pygame.Surface(screen.get_size())
    background = pygame.image.load("sand.jpg")
    background = pygame.transform.scale(background, screen.get_size())
    screen.blit(background, (0, 0))
    if number == 0:
        message = "Sorry try again..."
    elif number == 1:
        message = "The theif escapes!"
    else:
        message = "Onto the hunt for gold!"

    insFont = pygame.font.SysFont("Calibri", 25)
    insLabels = []
    instructions = (
        "Last score: %d" % score ,
        "%s" % message,
        "",
        "GOLD!",
        "Get all the gold before you are "
        "obliterated!",
        "Use arrow keys to move the thief.",
        "Space to start, Esc to quit."
        )

    for line in instructions:
        tempLabel = insFont.render(line, 1 , (0,0,0))
        insLabels.append(tempLabel)

    #set up homescreen loop
    keepGoing = True
    clock = pygame.time.Clock()
    while keepGoing:
        clock.tick(30)
        for event in pygame.event.get():
            if event.type == pygame.QUIT:
                keepGoing = False
                donePlaying = True
            if event.type == pygame.KEYDOWN:
                if event.key == pygame.K_SPACE:
                    keepGoing = False
                    donePlaying = False
                if event.key == pygame.K_ESCAPE:
                    keepGoing = False
                    donePlaying = True

        for i in range(len(insLabels)):
            screen.blit(insLabels[i], (50, 30*i))

        pygame.display.flip()

    return donePlaying

#define main function
def main():
    donePlaying = False
    score = 0
    message = ""
    while not donePlaying:
        donePlaying = instructions(score, message)
        if not donePlaying:
            score = game()
        else:
            pygame.quit()


if __name__ == "__main__":
    main()
```

Comment: Take a look at the traceback (which you should have shown us). On the last line of code it shows, there should be one or more attempts to create class instances. One of those calls is missing arguments. It doesn't have enough information to know what you want the new instance to look like. Do you see it? Do you see what information it needs?

Comment: a) *Which* `__init__` takes exactly three arguments? Show your traceback. b) You provide almost 350 lines of code, much, much more than the ones you need for your problem. You are much more likely to get an answer if you create a [short, self-contained example](http://sscce.org/) of your problem

Comment: Actually, this code doesn't even parse. If you take the code you've posted and try to run it, you'll get a `SyntaxError`. There's a chunk missing near where the error message will point to.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [\_\_init\_\_() takes exactly 2 arguments (1 given)?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25805194/init-takes-exactly-2-arguments-1-given)

Answer (score 1):

Glancing at your code, this line:

```
pirate = Pirate()
```

Your `Pirate` class expects `self`, `screen`, `dx`. You only implicitly provide `self`.

I can only guess at what you want, especially since I don't know off the bat what `dx` is supposed to mean in respect to your game, but this will probably at least avoid the error:

```
pirate = Pirate(pygame.display.get_surface(), 60)
```