# __init__() takes exactly 2 arguments (1 given)?

Tags: python

I would like to know where am lagging, Looking for your advices..

```
class Student_Record(object):

    def __init__(self,s):
        self.s="class_Library"
        print"Welcome!! take the benifit of the library"

    def Student_details(self):
        print " Please enter your details below"

a=raw_input("Enter your name :\n")
print ("your name is :" +a)
b=raw_input("Enter your USN :\n")
print ("Your USN is:" ,int(b))
c=raw_input("Enter your branch :\n")
print ("your entered baranch is" +c)
d=raw_input("Enter your current semester :\n")
print ("your in the semester",int(d))
rec=Student_Record()
rec.Student_details(self)
```

I am getting this error ..

TypeError: **init**() takes exactly 2 arguments (1 given)

Comment: `Student_Record()` .. forgot to pass an argument (for `s`). Or maybe have one parameter too many? Also, `rec.Student_details(self)` is wrong as Python *automatically* supplies the `self` parameter to methods.

Comment: The code shows that Python basics has to be enforced: apart from the error, the logic of the program itself must be adjusted

Answer (score 4):

Your `Student_Record.__init__()` method takes two arguments, `self` and `s`. `self` is provided for you by Python, but you failed to provide `s`.

You are ignoring `s` altogether, drop it from the function signature:

```
class Student_Record(object):
    def __init__(self):
        self.s = "class_Library"
        print"Welcome!! take the benifit of the library"
```

Next, you are calling the method `rec.Student_details()` passing in an argument, but *that* method only takes `self`, which is already provided for you by Python. You don't need to pass it in manually, and in your case the name is not even defined in that scope.

Answer (score 0):

if you do

```
class Student_Record(object):

    def __init__(self, s):
        self.s = ""

    def Student_details(self):
        print " Please enter your details below"
```

when you create the object of class `Student_Record` it should accept a parameter despite for itself (`self`). so it looks like:

```
record = Student_Record("text")
```

and in `__init__` you can do whatever with the passed-in variable `s`. For example, `self.s = s` and you can call it anywhere in the class with `self.s` because it has been initialized.

Answer (score 0):

Your code should be like this..(python indent):

```
class Student_Record(object):

    def __init__(self,s="class_Library"):
        self.s=s
        print"Welcome!! take the benifit of the library"

    def Student_details(self):
        print " Please enter your details below"
        a=raw_input("Enter your name :\n")
        print ("your name is :" +a)
        b=raw_input("Enter your USN :\n")
        print ("Your USN is:" ,int(b))
        c=raw_input("Enter your branch :\n")
        print ("your entered baranch is" +c)
        d=raw_input("Enter your current semester :\n")
        print ("your in the semester",int(d))

rec=Student_Record()

rec.Student_details()
```

`s` in `def __init__` should have a default value or you can pass a value from `rec=Student_Record()`.