# __init__() takes exactly 4 arguments (3 given)

Tags: python

Points are defined by giving the x and y coordinates. The distance between two points can be calculated by using the distance_from method. Points should have publicly available at least the following properties x, y and distance_from.

Circles are defined by giving the center point and the radius. Circle has the method is_inside that answers if the given point is inside the circle or not. Circles should have publicly available at least the following properties center, radius and is_inside.

The issue here is that i can't initiate my parent and base classes.

Side note: Funtions and classes distance_from, Circle, circle.is_inside only take one p.

```
import math
class Point():
    def __init__(self, xpoint, ypoint):
        self.xpoint = xpoint
        self.ypoint = ypoint
    def distance_from(xpoint, ypoint):
        distance = math.sqrt(((p1.xpoint-p2.xpoint)**2)+((p1.ypoint-p2.ypoint)**2))
        print(distance)
class Circle(Point):
    def __init__(self, xpoint, ypoint, r):
       super(Circle, self).__init__(xpoint, ypoint)
       self.r = r
    def is_inside(xpoint, ypoint):        
        if self.r > distance:
            print("False")
        else:             
            print("True") 
p1 = Point(0, 0) 
p2 = Point(2, 4) 
p1.distance_from(p2)
circle  = Circle(p2,4)
circle.is_inside(p1)
```

Comment: And what exactly is your problem? You copied the text of your homework, that's what I see so far.

Comment: What is your question?

Comment: distance_from and is_inside are missing the self argument at the beginning.

Comment: Javier, my distance_from function actually works

Comment: circle  = Circle(p2,4) must be changed to circle  = Circle(2, 4, 4)

Comment: Your distance function "works" because its getting the values from global scope. You should read about encapsulation in OOP.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [\_\_init\_\_() takes exactly 2 arguments (1 given)?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25805194/init-takes-exactly-2-arguments-1-given)

Answer (score 0):

Change your coe to this: I added comments to your mistakes

```
import math
class Point(object): # Add object here
    def __init__(self, xpoint, ypoint):
        self.xpoint = xpoint
        self.ypoint = ypoint
    def distance_from(self, xpoint, ypoint):  # Missing self here
        distance = math.sqrt(((p1.xpoint-p2.xpoint)**2)+((p1.ypoint-p2.ypoint)**2))
        print(distance)

class Circle(Point):
    def __init__(self, xpoint, ypoint, r):
        super(Circle, self).__init__(xpoint, ypoint)
        self.r = r
    def is_inside(self, point):  # Missing self here
        if self.r > self.distance_from(point.xpoint, point.ypoint): # You'll have to callculate distance here
            print("False")
        else:             
            print("True") 
p1 = Point(0, 0) 
p2 = Point(2, 4) 
p1.distance_from(p1.xpoint, p1.ypoint)  # Missing points
c  = Circle(p1.xpoint, p1.ypoint, 4)  # Missing points
c.is_inside(p2)
```

If you don't want to use super().**init** use this:

```
Point.__init__(self, xpoint, ypoint)  # Change super to the superclass name.  Add self to the init method
```

Comment: Dear Vincent, thanks for the help. Actually those you commented to be missing the p1 or p2, take only one p in the argument, either p1, or p2, or any p for the matter.

Comment: Is this what you ment? Btw distance is not initialized. Plus if you want to use the super init you'll need to add object in python 2.7

Comment: Can i do it without super?

Comment: Yes I'll add it to my answer

Answer (score 0):

Some notes:

- Member functions always have self as the first argument.
- Member functions should only access to variables accessible through self or the fuction parameters, never global scope.

  ```
  import math

  class Point(object):
      def __init__(self, xpoint, ypoint):
          self.xpoint = xpoint
          self.ypoint = ypoint

        # Here you where missing self and you were accessing p2 that exists in global scope.
      def distance_from(self, another_point):
            distance =  math.sqrt(((self.xpoint-another_point.xpoint)**2)+((self.ypoint-another_point.ypoint)**2))
            print(distance)


  class Circle(Point):
      def __init__(self, xpoint, ypoint, r):
        super(Circle, self).__init__(xpoint, ypoint)
        self.r = r

      def is_inside(self, another_point):
          # you forgot to calculate the distance
          if self.distance_from(another_point) < self.r:
              print("True")
          else:
              print("False")

  p1 = Point(0, 0)
  p2 = Point(2, 4)
  p1.distance_from(p2)

  #create a circle centered at 2,4 with radius 4
  circle  = Circle(2, 4, 4)
  circle.is_inside(p1) # returns "True"
  ```

Comment: Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "point_circle_tests.py", line 4, in <module>
    from geometry import Point,Circle
  File "/tmp/grader/20141125082952410825/geometry.py", line 31, in <module>
    circle.is_inside(p1)
  File "/tmp/grader/20141125082952410825/geometry.py", line 20, in is_inside
    if self.distance_from(another_point) < self.r:
TypeError: unorderable types: NoneType() < int()

Comment: The code works just fine. By the way, the error path in you error, "/tmp/grader/20141125082952410825/" clearly shows that you are submitting my answer as your homework. **NOT COOL**.

Answer (score -1):

When calling `__init__` manually you must provide the `self` argument.

Comment: `self` was already present in the method. The error is related to other arguments.