# __init__() takes exactly 4 arguments (1 given)

Tags: python, django

form.py

```
class InvoiceForm(ModelForm,):

    def __init__(self,em,first,last):
        self.email=em
        self.first=first
        self.last=last
        super(InvoiceForm,self).__init__(self,em,first,last)
        self.fields['email']=forms.ChoiceField(choices=[x.email for x in AuthUser.objects.filter(email=em)])
        self.fields['first']=forms.ChoiceField(choices=[x.first_name for x in AuthUser.objects.filter(first_name=first)])
        self.fields['last']=forms.ChoiceField(choices=[x.last_name for x in AuthUser.objects.filter(last_name=last)]) 
    total_credits_ordered=forms.IntegerField(label=mark_safe('<br/> total_credits_ordered'))
    total_mobile_cr_ordered=forms.IntegerField(label=mark_safe('<br/> total_mobile_cr_ordered'))
    total_cloud_cr_ordered=forms.IntegerField(label=mark_safe('<br/> total_cloud_cr_ordered'))
    invoice_currency=forms.CharField(label=mark_safe('<br/> invoice_currency'),max_length=100)
    invoice_currency_code=forms.IntegerField(label=mark_safe('<br/>invoice_currency_code '))
    invoice_country=forms.CharField(label=mark_safe('<br/> invoice_country'),max_length=100)
    invoice_note=forms.CharField(label=mark_safe('<br/> invoice_note'),max_length=100)


    class Meta:
        model=Invoices
        fields=['total_credits_ordered','total_mobile_cr_ordered','total_cloud_cr_ordered','invoice_currency','invoice_currency_code','invoice_country','invoice_note']
```

views.py

```
def test(request):
    from app.tests import model_tests
    m = model_tests()
    print "assf"


    try:

        if request.method=="POST":
            print "sff"
            m.create_user_types()
            cform=CustomerForm(request.POST)
            if cform.is_valid():
                em=cform.cleaned_data['email']
                username=email
                password = cform.cleaned_data['password']
                first=cform.cleaned_data['first']
                last=cform.cleaned_data['last']  
                companyname=cform.cleaned_data['company_name']
                companyaddr=cform.cleaned_data['company_addr']
                companystate=cform.cleaned_data['company_state']
                companycountry=cform.cleaned_data['company_country']
                id=m.create_customer(username,email,password,first,last,companyname,companyaddr,companystate,companycountry) 
                print "SFsfg"
                iform=InvoiceForm(email,first,last)
                print "ggg"
                if iform.is_valid():
                    tco=iform.cleaned_data['total_credits_ordered']
                    tmco=iform.cleaned_data['total_mobile_cr_ordered']
                    tcco=iform.cleaned_data['total_cloud_cr_ordered']
                    ic=iform.cleaned_data['invoice_currency']
                    icc=iform.cleaned_data['invoice_currency_code']
                    c=iform.cleaned_data['invoice_country']
                    inote=iform.cleaned_data['invoice_note']
                    id_i=m.create_invoices(id,tco,tmco,tcco,ic,icc,c,inote) 
                    pform=PaymentForm()
                    print "dsf"
                    pform=PaymentForm(request.POST)
                    if pform.is_valid():            
                        tpm=pform.cleaned_data['total_payment_made']
                        ps=pform.cleaned_data['payment_status']
                        pt=pform.cleaned_data['payment_type']
                        m.create_payment(id_i,tpm,ps,pt)    
                        return HttpResponse("test successful") 
        else:
            print "d"
            cform=CustomerForm()
            iform=InvoiceForm() 
            pform=PaymentForm()                                      
        return render(request, 'test.html', {'cform': cform,'iform':iform,'pform':pform})
    except Exception as e:
        return HttpResponse("Exception : %s" %(e))
    return HttpResponse("Tests Successfull...")
```

It is showing:
`Exception : __init__() takes exactly 4 arguments (1 given)`

but I have passed parameters to the form.

Comment: Are you sure about that? I can see on the line that is 6 lines from the bottom that you dont

Comment: also include stacktrace please, not only the message.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [\_\_init\_\_() takes exactly 2 arguments (1 given)?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25805194/init-takes-exactly-2-arguments-1-given)

Answer (score 1):

We don't have the stacktrace in the question but problem is probably here:

```
else:
    print "d"
    cform=CustomerForm()
    iform=InvoiceForm() 
    pform=PaymentForm()
```

Here you are creating objects without passing any parameters. Since the instance itself is always passed, the message says that it misses the other parameters which are `em,first,last`

I suggest that you remove everything after the `else` part since it does nothing useful or a warning like this to avoid silent errors:

```
else:
     print("Unsupported method "+request.method)
```

Comment: can you please tell me how to do that

Comment: In your form __init__ you are telling the form to expect 4 parameters self, em, first and last. So when you declare your form without arguments such as CustomerForm() init function is looking for those 3 other things because only 'self' is being passed. You need to assign a default to em first and last.

Comment: I don't know if copying my answer will make the OP understand. Not that I blame you for that, no!

Comment: @jersy: see my edit you don't need to do anything in the `else` part.

Comment: If  i remove all things from else part, It is giving exception  like this exception : local variable 'cform' referenced before assignment.

Comment: Here form is creating in that else part only

Comment: you could create `cform` out of the loop: `cform=CustomerForm(request.method)`, problem is the other variables. Your code is incomplete: it only supports `POST`. You have to complete it. Period.